# BibLaTex authoryear style multiple authors wrong formatting

Tags: biblatex, author

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
    This is a cite \cite{paassen2016linear}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with the `bib.bib` file

```
@inproceedings{paassen2016linear,
    title={Linear supervised transfer learning for generalized matrix LVQ},
    author={Paa{\ss}en, Benjamin and Schulz, Alexander and Hammer, Barbara},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the Workshop New Challenges in Neural Computation 2016},
    number={4},
    year={2016}
}
```

leads to the reference formatting `name1, firstname1, firstname2 name2 and firstname3 name3` instead of `firstname1 name1, firstname2 name2 and firstname3 name3` (see figure).

Same, if I go with bibtex as backend and change author list to `author={first1 last1 and first2 last2 and first3 last3}`.
What's going wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Nothing is wrong: This is the default setting. You can easily change that with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` (or `\DeclareNameAlias{given-family}`).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534462/35864

Comment: Wow, that easy! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This slightly unusual order is the intended default setting. You can read about it at [Why a comma appears for the first author of the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534462/35864).

Most people who are not happy with this order usually prefer

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

In total

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Goossens, Michel, Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander (1994).//Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf (1998).]