# Why are footcite and printbibliography interpreting the author differently?

Tags: biblatex

My bibtex entry is looking like this:

```
    @book{Stephan2005,
    author = {Anke, Stephan},
    title = {Erinnertes Leben: Autobiographien, Memoiren und Oral-History-In-terviews als historische Quellen},
    year = {2005},
    location = {München},
}
```

There I get this output with `\footcite`:

> Stephan Anke. Erinnertes Leben: Autobiographien, Memoiren und
> Oral-History-In-terviews als historische Quellen. München, 2005, S.
> 14.

That's how I want it. last name first, no comma

`\printbibliography` prints this:

> Anke, Stephan. Erinnertes Leben: Autobiographien, Memoiren und
> Oral-History-In-terviews als historische Quellen. München, 2005.

Names not switched and comma after first name.

Even more strange:

```
@online{Ammerer2011,
author = {Heinrich, Ammerer and Elfriede, Windischbauer},
editor = {Zentrum polis – Politik Lernen in der Schule},
title = {Kompetenzorientierter Unterricht inGeschichte und Politischer Bildung:Diagnoseaufgaben mit Bildern},
year = {2011},
url = {https://www.ph-online.ac.at/phst/voe_main2.getVollText?pDocumentNr=64434&pCurrPk=3902},
urldate = {2020-07-21},
}
```

`\printbiblopgraphy` gets me

> Ammerer, Heinrich und Windischbauer Elfriede. Kompetenzorientierter
> Unterricht inGeschichte und Politischer Bildung:Diagnoseaufgaben mit
> Bildern. Hrsg. von Zentrum polis – Politik Lernen in der Schule. 2011.
> url: https://www.ph- online.ac.at/phst/voe_main2.
> getVollText?pDocumentNr=64434&pCurrPk=3902 (besucht am 21. 07. 2020).

Here the first name is separated by comma and switched and the second is as I wanted it to be.

and `\footcite` does this:

> Heinrich Ammerer und Windischbauer Elfriede. Kompetenzorientierter
> Unterricht inGeschichte und Politischer Bildung:Diagnoseaufgaben mit
> Bildern. Hrsg. von Zentrum polis – Politik Lernen in der Schule.
> 2011. url: https : / / www . ph - online . ac . at / phst / voe _ main2 . getVollText ? pDocumentNr = 64434 & pCurrPk=3902 (besucht am
> 21. 07. 2020), S. 6.

First name is switched but no comma and second name is correct.

The style used is "verbose"

Any ideas what leads to this behaviour?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The correct input for simple names with only given and family name parts is either

- `<Given> <Family>` as in

  ```
  Emma Sigfridsson
  ```
- or `<Family>, <Given>` as in

  ```
  Sigfridsson, Emma
  ```

See also [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864).

So all the names in the example entries are switched in the input. The correct entries would be

```
@book{Stephan2005,
  author   = {Anke Stephan},
  title    = {Erinnertes Leben: Autobiographien, Memoiren
              und Oral-History-Interviews als historische Quellen},
  year     = {2005},
  location = {München},
}
@online{Ammerer2011,
  author  = {Heinrich Ammerer and Elfriede Windischbauer},
  editor  = {Zentrum polis – Politik Lernen in der Schule},
  title   = {Kompetenzorientierter Unterricht in Geschichte
             und Politischer Bildung: Diagnoseaufgaben mit Bildern},
  year    = {2011},
  url     = {https://www.ph-online.ac.at/phst/voe_main2.getVollText?pDocumentNr=64434&pCurrPk=3902},
  urldate = {2020-07-21},
}
```

This wasn't immediately obvious for me in the `Stephan2005` entry (because both Anke and Stephan could be the given name), but it is quite clear for `Ammerer2011`.

With that input we get

[image: footcite: Heinrich Ammerer und Elfriede Windischbauer.//bibliography: Ammerer, Heinrich und Elfriede Windischbauer.]

The reason is that `biblatex` tries to use the 'natural' name order `<Given> <Family>` as much as possible. Since names are traditionally sorted in `<Family>, <Given>` order, however, `biblatex` uses that order for the first name in the bibliography so that the word that determines the sorting position in the bibliography is the first. See [Why a comma appears for the first author of the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534462/35864) for more discussions about the background.

Specifically, the code responsible for that is from `biblatex.def`

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{given-family}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family}
```

from `authortitle.bbx`

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}
```

and from `verbose.cbx`

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

This means that normally (`default`) `biblatex` uses the format `given-family`. But for `author`, `editor` and `translator` at the beginning of an entry, it uses `sortname`, which is `family-given/given-family`. Yet in the full citation of your `verbose` `sortname` is explicitly reset to the natural `default` format.

So you should be able to modify all name formats to your wishes by redefining the name formats `sortname` and `default` and/or by dropping or changing `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}` in the definition of `cite:full`.

If I understand correctly the following might come closer to what you want

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose, backend=biber]{biblatex}

% <Family> <Given> order
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

% no comma
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

% to distinguish FAMILY and Given name better
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Stephan2005,
  author   = {Anke Stephan},
  title    = {Erinnertes Leben: Autobiographien, Memoiren
              und Oral-History-Interviews als historische Quellen},
  year     = {2005},
  location = {München},
}
@online{Ammerer2011,
  author  = {Heinrich Ammerer and Elfriede Windischbauer},
  editor  = {Zentrum polis – Politik Lernen in der Schule},
  title   = {Kompetenzorientierter Unterricht in Geschichte
             und Politischer Bildung: Diagnoseaufgaben mit Bildern},
  year    = {2011},
  url     = {https://www.ph-online.ac.at/phst/voe_main2.getVollText?pDocumentNr=64434&pCurrPk=3902},
  urldate = {2020-07-21},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % only for this example
Lorem \autocite{Stephan2005}
ipsum \autocite{Ammerer2011}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ammerer Heinrich und Windischbauer Elfriede.]

---

Not directly related to the question, but on second glance, the entry `Ammerer2011` might be better represented as a `@collection`. After all Heinrich Ammerer and Elfriede Windischbauer are editors (*Herausgeber*) and not authors.

```
@collection{Ammerer2011,
  editor     = {Heinrich Ammerer and Elfriede Windischbauer},
  title      = {Kompetenzorientierter Unterricht in Geschichte
                und Politischer Bildung: Diagnoseaufgaben mit Bildern},
  year       = {2011},
  publisher  = {Zentrum polis – Politik Lernen in der Schule},
  location   = {Wien},
  url        = {https://www.ph-online.ac.at/phst/voe_main2.getVollText?pDocumentNr=64434&pCurrPk=3902},
  urldate    = {2020-07-21},
}
```

For `Stephan2005` `@book` looks a bit unusual as well. I'd be inclined to make it a `@report`.

```
@report{Stephan2005,
  author   = {Anke Stephan},
  title    = {Erinnertes Leben: Autobiographien, Memoiren
              und Oral-History-Interviews als historische Quellen},
  year     = {2005},
  type     = {Digitales Handbuch zur Geschichte und Kultur Russlands und Osteuropas},
  number   = {10},
  doi      = {https://doi.org/10.5282/ubm/epub.6270},
  location = {München},
}
```